# Ruby: FileUtils.cp truncates file; FileUtils.mv it does not?

Tags: ruby, shell, file-io, truncation

This is weird… and I can't figure out for the life of me why it's doing it this way.

1. I've got a folder full of various CoffeeScript, SASS, HTML, and XML files.
2. I've got a **Ruby script** that's taking them all, compiling them, and minifying them into one master XML file (it's for iGoogle Gadget development).

   - This script takes command line args using `trollop` (I only state this to clarify my code below).
3. I want this script to copy this file from the current directory where it's created to a destination directory where it will be run.

So far, the building/compiling/minifying step runs like magic. It's #3 that's borked to Twilight Zone-level.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
…
if opts[:deploy_local]
  FileUtils.cp 'build.xml', '/path/to/destination/'
  puts "Copied #{written_file_name} to #{output_destination}." if opts[:verbose]
end
```

When this copies the file, the destination file is truncated about 3/4 of the way through it. The source file is just fine. However, **moving the file works like a charm**, for some strange reason.

```
  FileUtils.mv 'build.xml', '/path/to/destination/'
```

To add another level of weirdness, if I just do a system copy, it also gets truncated.

```
  system("cp build.xml /path/to/destination")
```

FWIW, I'm running this script from `zsh` and not `bash`. In both instances (copying and moving) the source and destination files are not in use by any other process.

Can anybody explain this freaky behavior?

Comment: Move's are atomic, so you definitely won't have a problem there.  Have you closed the file before you try copying it?

Comment: Yep. I'll update my question with that in mind.

Comment: Could there be a quota in effect? Move wouldn't use more quota but copy would.
Can it be run from zsh command-line? What behaviour do you get then?

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

- Are you moving to the same disk volume?  If so, then, yeah, cam's comment about atomicity is definitely true; the OS is probably just messing with the inode table during a move, as opposed to writing out the data.  IF you're moving the data between volumes, then it wouldn't be so simple.
- Have you tried passing

  ```
  :verbose => true
  ```

  to the FileUtils.cp command?  That might give a diagnostic about the failure.