# How to pull from git media

Tags: git

I am trying to work with git-media. I have configured git media and added files to one  repository so that those will go to separate location instead of storing in .git folder. This works fine. Now I have cloned repository. Now I am trying to pull. When making pull, file names will come to cloned repo. but it contains only link.(Nearly 1KB size).Actuall content of file will not come. I tried by configuring cloned repo with git- media. but Still file content will not come. What could be the issue. Please help.

Comment: Where do you store the files? scp share? - there's an open pull request for scp...

Comment: No I am storing in local. [git-media]
 Transport = "local"
 localpath = "C:\\Users\\VX\\Desktop\\GitMedia\\LohithFileServer"

Comment: This might be a ruby issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459553/ruby-fileutils-cp-truncates-file-fileutils-mv-it-does-not

Comment: Is there any open pull request for local. Like in git annex : git annex get .